# Create Custom Route in MVC 5 for Date

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to convert the below url

https://localhost:44322/BankHoliday/NewBankHoliday?holidayDate=08%2F25%2F2016%2000%3A00%3A00&countryID=GBR

to
https://localhost:44322/BankHoliday/NewBankHoliday/holidayDate/08-25-2016/countryID/GBR

I have tried this code but it does not work

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                null,
                "{holidayDate}/{countryID}",
                new { Controller = "BankHoliday", action = "NewBankHoliday" }, new { holidayDate = @"\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}" }
            );
```

Comment: How are you generating the url (using `Html.ActionLink()`)?

Comment: I am using  @Html.ActionLink@Html.ActionLink("MY DATA", "NewBankHoliday", new { holidayDate = item.BankHolidayDate, countryID = item.CountryID }, new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-trash" })

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve a url of `BankHoliday/NewBankHoliday/holidayDate/08-25-2016/countryID/GBR`, you route definition would need to be

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Bank",
    url: "BankHoliday/NewBankHoliday/holidayDate/{holidayDate}/countryID/{countryID}",
    defaults: new { controller = "BankHoliday", action = "NewBankHoliday"}
);
```

and located before the default route. It unclear why you want the text `holidayDate` and `countryID` in the route and a more conventional url would be

```
url: "BankHoliday/NewBankHoliday/{holidayDate}/{countryID}",
```

to generate `BankHoliday/NewBankHoliday/08-25-2016/GBR`

Then the controller method will need to be

```
public class BankHolidayController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult NewBankHoliday(DateTime holidayDate, string countryID)
    {
        ....
```

assuming the culture on your server accepts dates in `MM-dd-yyyy` format.

and to generate the link in the view

```
@Html.ActionLink("Your Link Text", "NewBankHoliday", "BankHoliday", new { holidayDate = "08-25-2016", countryID = "GBD"}, null)
```

Comment: I am using  @Html.ActionLink@Html.ActionLink("MY DATA", "NewBankHoliday", new { holidayDate = item.BankHolidayDate, countryID = item.CountryID }, new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-trash" })

Comment: I am getting an exception   on my                                                                                          https://localhost:44322/BankHoliday/NewBankHoliday/08/25/2016%2000%3a00%3a00/GBR.                                                                                        A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).

Comment: @maxspan - you need to make sure that `holidayDate` contains the string formatted date with dashes, not slashes.

Comment: So you server does not support that date format. In that case you waill need to use `new { holidayDate = item.BankHolidayDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), countryID = item.CountryID }` although that will then result in `.../BankHoliday/NewBankHoliday/2016-08-25/GBR` (i.e ISO format) which will still correctly bind to the `DateTime` parameter

Comment: You cannot have 2 `null` parameters and use a route definition (only the last parameter can be optional). If you provided only one of the values then it would use query string values again. Is there any reason you don't want to pass both values?

Comment: Its working with 2 parameters and both nullable. Thank you.

Comment: Yes but it wont if you only supplied one of them - either the date or the country. What is the purpose for making the date parameter `nullable`?